# Django and Php Sites on single Apache Server

Tags: php, python, django, apache, amazon-ec2

I have a Django site running on ec2 instance (ubuntu) on apache2 using mod_wsgi. I have placed it in /var/www/django_project. It is Up and running without any issues. Now i want to host another site (php, mysql) on this ec2 instance only. I tried to configure my httpd.conf and added php directory with proper permissions, but I believe due to Alias setting in mod_wsgi, any request above '/' is taken up by django.

I DO NOT have any domain name. I access my Django site with IP of machine (i.e w.x.y.z/django_app).

Correct me if I am wrong : Since i do not have server name, I cannot have both site running on port 80 using virtual Hosts.

And I do not mind running them on different ports either. Please suggest me a way to host php site on this server. which file to configure and how to configure it.

My httpd.conf file:

```
Alias /static /var/www/resumerepo/static
<Directory /var/www/resumerepo/static>
order deny,allow
Allow From All
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/resumerepo/resumerepo/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath  /var/www/resumerepo

<Directory /var/www/resumerepo>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow From All
</Files>

</Directory>
```

It works fine and my app is accessible. However if i put it in one virtual host and make another virtual host, apache restart throws an error saying PythonPath can not be in virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this easily if your django project is accessible via the root of your domain (or your IP), for example: `http://1.2.3.4` -> leads to your django project`.

I think, one solution could be to move your django project to a subdirectory, like `http://1.2.3.4/django`, and make your php project also accessible in subdirectory, like `http://1.2.3.4/php`.

Or you can create a new virtual host, listening on port 8080, for example, for your php project. This way :

- `http://1.2.3.4` leads to your django project
- `http://1.2.3.4:8080` leads to your php project

The second option may be easier to set up, as you won't have to change config for your django project.

Your vhost file could look like :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin contact@yourdomain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php

    <Directory /var/www/php>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe this won't work : according to Apache documentation, [you should not use virtual hosts without ServerName](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations#Not_setting_a_ServerName_in_a_virtual_host.).